# CoreData - fetch objects by relationship in a batch for better performance

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

### Introduction

Whenever possible, I'm trying to use find-or-create pattern in core data. When I'm doing this for a set of items that are identifiable by an id (doesn't matter if string or int), I do this in a batch (as oposed to do one fetch per item):

```
let itemIDs = Set(items.map { $0.id })
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<E>(entityName: E.entityName())
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", itemIDs)
let foundObjects = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

### Problem

I have an entity that is not identifiable by an id but rather by its relationships to other entities

```
ItemPosition
===============
attributes:
- position
---------------
relationships:
- endpoint: N:1
- item: N:1
```

The unique key here is combination of `endpoint` and `item`.

For this entity, I do one fetch per item as I don't know how to do it in a batch:

```
var foundObjects: [ItemPosition] = []
for item in items {
   let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<E>(entityName: E.entityName())
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "item = %@ AND endpoint = %@", item, endpoint)
   let results = try! context.fetch(fetchRequest)
   if let position = results.first {
       foundObjects.append(position)
   }
}
```

This is not optimal as it hits SQL database for every item and I would like to avoid that.

### Question

Is there a way how to fetch objects by multiple relationships in a batch? Something similar to `NSPredicate(format: "id IN %@", itemIDs)` metioned above?

Comment: Have considered doing an initial fetch of the Entities then calling `.filter` on the array of objects returned? This would allow you remove the object you want or don't need.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this, but neither is particularly elegant. You could use a compound OR predicate:

```
var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
    for item in items {
        predicates.append(NSPredicate(format: "item = %@ AND endpoint = %@", item, endpoint))
    }
    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate.init(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
    let results = try! context.fetch(compoundPredicate)
```

Or you could generate an id for the ItemPosition objects by appending endpoint and item ids, and fetch by that?